# Yii2 REST API as Module route configuration

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2

I have an existing Yii2 application and have been trying to implement a REST API as an additional module (Maybe a module isn't the correct way to go about this?) But I'm having some trouble configuring the route structures. It doesn't quite work and doesn't follow the expected results, based of the [following guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html).

I've built an additional module that looks like this:

```
module
  api
    controllers
      UserController.php
    Module.php
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\api\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

**Module.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\api;

/**
 * onco module definition class
 */
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $defaultController = 'user';
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\api\controllers';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

In my config file I have the added following:

```
'request' => [
    ...
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
    ...
    'urlManager' => [
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false, // have tried as true also
    'rules' => [
     ...
     ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => '\app\modules\api\controllers\user'],
            ],
     ],
     ...
     'modules' => [
      ...
      'api' => [ // module for RESTful API
            'class' => 'app\modules\api\Module',
        ],
    ]
```

When I run the following urls through postman I get the following:

- http://localhost/site1/web/api/users -> 404
- http://localhost/site1/web/api/users/index -> 404
- http://localhost/site1/web/api/user/index -> returns json repsonse
- http://localhost/site1/web/api/user/2 -> 404

I'm unsure as to why the predicted routes of noted in the docs as:

> Trying it Out With the above minimal amount of effort, you have
>   already finished your task of creating the RESTful APIs for accessing
>   the user data. The APIs you have created include: 
>   GET /users: list all users page by page;
>
> HEAD /users: show the overview information of user listing;
>
> POST /users: create a new user;
>
> GET /users/123: return the details of the user 123;
>
> HEAD /users/123: show the overview information of user 123;
>
> PATCH /users/123 and PUT /users/123: update the user 123;
>
> DELETE /users/123: delete the user 123;
>
> OPTIONS /users: show the supported verbs regarding endpoint /users;
>
> OPTIONS /users/123: show the supported verbs regarding endpoint /users/123

What have I likely done wrong in this setup? Is there a better way to implement an API into an existing website, whilst maintaining DRY practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
         [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
            'controller' => ['api/user'],
         ]
    ]
],
...
'modules' => [
  ...
  'api' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/api',
        'class' => 'app\modules\api\Module',
    ],
]
```

Also be sure to implement prettyUrl's [related server server configs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration).

Comment: Pretty urls are already enabled for the site as it is. I tried your changes but got the same result :-(

Comment: `'controller' => ['api/user']` did you try it with `'enableStrictParsing' => true` ?

Comment: I think it might have worked. I'm able to access http://localhost/site1/web/users and http://localhost/site1/web/users/2 to get info back. Just confirming other reqs

Comment: when I first answered I wrongly put `'controller' => ['users' => 'api/user']` which I soon updated to `'controller' => ['api/user']` as the first removes the `api` from url endpoint by directly mapping `users` to the required controller. is there any chance that you did copy my first code before I fix it ? :)

Comment: It currently works (so far, I think). I am using Yii2-admin, so trying to allow the route `api/user` in the `as access` param to bypass the authentication. But currently it's not letting me. the route `/web/api/users/161` and `/web/api/users` work so far in the browser though it seems. So certainly closer :-)

Comment: you didn't answer my question. did you set `'controller' => ['users' => 'api/user']` or `'controller' => ['api/user']` ?

Comment: It's currently set as this: `'controller' =>  ['api/user']`. I'm accessing routes as `/web/api/users/161`. Which is the route structure I ideally wanted

Comment: great. I have no idea what else could be wrong but [this tutorial](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template) was useful to me once when implementing it [here](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/tree/master/backend/api) and [here](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/tree/master/backend/auth). have a look at it maybe you'll find what else could be missing.